# Overriding methods in subclassed Python enums

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

From [PEP 435](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/#restricted-subclassing-of-enumerations) on subclassing enums the following is allowed:

```
>>> class Foo(Enum):
...   def some_behavior(self):
...     pass
...
>>> class Bar(Foo):
...   happy = 1
...   sad = 2
...
```

Say I want to define `some_behavior` in a different manner for the `happy` and `sad` enums.

Is there a better way to do that than something like:

```
>>> class Bar(Foo):
...   happy = 1
...   sad = 2
...   def some_behavior(self):
...       if self is Bar.happy:
...           # happy behavior
...       elif self is Bar.sad:
...           # sad behavior
```

That looks clunky to me.

Comment: The standard way to test an enum's identity is with `is` (e.g. `self is Bar.happy`).  Is there a reason you're not using that?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is<sup>1</sup>.

The trick is in overriding `__getattribute__`, which intercepts *all* name lookups and is highly dangerous<sup>2</sup>:

```
class Foo(Enum):

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        # overriding this method is dangerous!
        #
        # enum member value must be an instance of a class
        value_dict = super().__getattribute__('_value_').__class__.__dict__
        if name in value_dict:
            # bind the enum member instance to the method and return it
            return partial(value_dict[name], self)
        else:
            # otherwise return the found object unchanged
            return super().__getattribute__(name)

    def __repr__(self):
        # clean up the repr()
        return '<%s.%s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.name)
```

Add a small helper function:

```
def member(cls):
    # convert the class into an instance of itself
    return cls()
```

Then write the final `Enum`:

```
class Bar(Foo):

    #
    # default methods
    #
    def some_behavior(self):
        return self.name + ' is neutral'

    def likes_to(self):
        return 'likes to sit'

    #
    # members
    #
    @member
    class happy:
        # overridden methods
        def some_behavior(self):
            return self.name + ' is happy'
        def likes_to(self):
            return 'likes to dance'

    @member
    class sad:
        # overridden method
        def some_behavior(self):
            return self.name + ' is sad'

    @member
    class okay:
        # uses default methods
        pass
```

And in use:

```
>>> list(Bar)
[<Bar.happy>, <Bar.sad>, <Bar.okay>]

>>> Bar.happy.some_behavior()
'happy is happy'

>>> Bar.happy.likes_to()
'likes to dance'

>>> Bar.sad.some_behavior()
'sad is sad'

>>> Bar.sad.likes_to()
'likes to sit'

>>> Bar.okay.some_behavior()
'okay is neutral'

>>> Bar.okay.likes_to()
'likes to sit'
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Definitely not idiomatic.

<sup>2</sup>Overriding `__getattribute__` is dangerous because it controls how attributes are handled -- for example, descriptor magic is implemented in `object.__getattribute__`.  Any mistake here can cause difficult to debug problems

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't.

I mean, you might be able to do something like this:

```
def some_behavior(self):
    return {Bar.happy: some_function
            Bar.sad: some_other_function}[self](arguments?)
```

Or like this:

```
def some_behavior(self):
    custom_thing = {Bar.happy: some_function
                    Bar.sad: some_other_function}[self]
    # do something which is the same for both
    custom_thing()
    # do something else the same for both
```

But unless `some_function` etc. already exist, this may not be significantly better than what you have now (though you might be able to save a level or two of indentation, I suppose).  You can use lambdas here, but that gets ugly quite fast, and I don't recommend it except in the simplest of cases (which can often be handled with [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) anyway).

As discussed in the comments, you *can* do something like this:

```
class Foo(Enum):
    happy = 1
    sad = 2

def happy_behavior():  # No self argument!
    self = Foo.happy  # only if you need self
    ...

def sad_behavior():
    self = Foo.sad
    ...

Foo.happy.some_behavior = happy_behavior
Foo.sad.some_behavior = sad_behavior
```

This is rather ugly, in my opinion, but it should work in all reasonable situations, including expressions like `Foo(1).some_behavior()` or `Foo['sad'].some_behavior()`.  However, it may confuse static type checkers and/or linters.

Comment: You are right. Lambdas wouldn't be beneficial in the long run. Some Javascript like syntax: `happy.some_behavior = def() { # do happy stuff }`, would have been useful here, which degenerates to Python not having anonymous functions except lambdas.

Comment: You can manually assign functions like that, actually, but it's not idiomatic IMHO.  All Python functions are first-class, not just lambdas.